# Not able to push data in an empty array, I'm getting that data from an external api, using https module in Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, https, get

```js
var https = require("https");
const arr = [];
for (let i = 1; i < 26; i++) {
  https.get(
    `https://jsonmock.hackerrank.com/api/countries?page=${i}`,
    (res) => {
      res.on("data", (data) => {
        JSON.parse(data).data.map((info, i) => {
          let { name } = info;
          arr.push(name);
          console.log(name);
        });
      });
    }
  );
}

console.log(arr);
```

when I'm just logging JSON.parse(data) I'm getting the required data on my console

but When I'm trying to push it into an array it's not happening instead it logs an empty array onto the console

really need to know the reason as I'm stuck with this for 3 days now

Comment: the callback to `https.get` - i.e. `(res) =>` is called *asynchronously* - therefore, `console.log(arr);` is executed *before* the 25 `https.get` requests are even made - you'll see that arr.push does work, if you `console.log(arr);` where you `console.log(name);`

Comment: Okay got that. Is there any way that I can log that data after the execution of the function is over like I'm trying above

Comment: yes there is - do you know how to code for asynchronous operations? That's how - what version of node.js? If it's a version with top-level await, makes it easier. If it's a version with native `fetch`, makes it trivial

Comment: No I have very little idea about asynchronous operations are there any resources ?? Or is there anything you can show me

Comment: yes there are - node.js has wonderful documentation - what version of node are you running - you seem to have failed to answer that part of my question - one thing to note, the way you are approaching this can result in that data in `arr` being out of sequence too - since you may get the responses out of order

Comment: Node v14.16.0.   Node js documentation has plethora of stuff can you suggest to me something specific

Comment: Sure, node.js has a plethora of "stuff" - node.js also had a plethora of releases after 14.16.0, and that's just in the 14.x series, let alone 15.x and 16.x

Comment: Can you suggest me something related to my question?

Comment: I've posted an answer - but you won't get `arr` on the top level like you want without a later version of node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that the callback to `https.get` - i.e. `(res) =>` is called *asynchronously* - therefore, `console.log(arr);` is executed before the 25 `https.get` requests are even made - you'll see that `arr.push` does actually work if you `console.log(arr);` where you `console.log(name);` - so your assumption that you are not able to push is incorrect

You are pushing to the array, you just never console.log the array when it has data in it

I guess one way I can suggest doing this with rather old version of Node.js you are using (14.16.0) is as follows

```
var https = require("https");
function fn(callback) {
    const result = [];
    let done = 0;
    for (let i = 1; i < 26; i++) {
        https.get(`https://jsonmock.hackerrank.com/api/countries?page=${i}`, (res) => {
            res.on("data", (data) => {
                JSON.parse(data).data.map((info) => {
                    let { name } = info;
                    result.push(name);
                    console.log(name);
                });
                // keep track of how many requests have "completed"
                done = done + 1;
                // when all are done, call the callback
                if (done === 25) {
                    callback(result);
                }
            });
        });
    }
}
fn(arr => { // here is where arr is populated, nowhere else
    console.log(arr);
});
```

Note, `arr` will only be accessible inside the callback - you will NOT be able to access `arr` at the top-level like you want - the only possible way you could  is to use a version of Node.js that supports top-level `await` - and convert the code to use `Promise` (which is a trivial task)

Not sure it's important, but there's no guarantee that the names in `arr` will be in the correct order ... i.e. the results from iteration 3 may be pushed after iteration 4, for example, since that's the nature of network requests, there is no guarantee when they will finish

---

> As an aside. If you were to use the latest (18.1 at the time of writing) version of node.js - the above can be written like

```
const promises = Array.from({length:25}, async (_, i) => {
    const res = await fetch(`https://jsonmock.hackerrank.com/api/countries?page=${i+1}`);
    const data = await res.json();
    return data.map(({name}) => name);
});
const arr = (await Promise.all(promises)).flat(2);
console.log(arr);
```

Things of note are

1. native `fetch` - which makes networks requests simple compared to regular node.js methods
2. top-level `await` - so, you can use `arr` at the top-level of the code
3. 6 lines of code vs over 20

Comment: okay got that code .So where can I start learning asynchronous operations in node js because as I have googled I found a [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Introducing) link . After reading it its not much helpful

Comment: @AyushSrivastava I won't recommend where to start learning the basics javascript - I would recommend you try to understand the code in the answer first

Comment: Cool. I'm getting your code now . Was figuring out a way to use async and await using HTTPS module but it doesn't support it. So one more question in node 18.x the fetch method you have mentioned is the same as the Web API fetch method.And i'm understanding asynchronous code much better thanks

Comment: converting https.get etc to Promises is quite trivial actually - wrap the call in a `new Promise` and resolve or reject as appropriate